# How do you change the location of the FPS counter in World of Warcraft?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Pressing the default hot key, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> I am able to view the FPS that World of Warcraft is running at.

Unfortunately, this counter is in the middle of my screen, and constantly changes position whenever I log in, teleport places, or enter instances.

How do you set a fixed spot for the FPS counter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tricky, but possible.

The FPS display is no normal UI element. It's a simple Label ("FPS") and Text (the number as a String). That's probably why you have issues with its positioning (and some addons may not find it).

So...

1. Use the [MoveAnything](https://wow.curseforge.com/projects/move-anything) addon. Look for *Framerate* and you should be able to move it around. It used to work, but I can't confirm it for BfA.
2. Use a macro to toggle it and move it to a specific position:

Code:

```
 /run FramerateLabel:ClearAllPoints() FramerateText:ClearAllPoints()
 FramerateLabel:SetPoint("RIGHT",UIParent,"CENTER",X,Y)
 FramerateText:SetPoint("LEFT",FramerateLabel,"RIGHT")
 ToggleFramerate()
```

X and Y are the coordinates relatively to the center of your screen. Negative values go left/down and the positive ones up/right:

```
   Y
-X C X
  -Y
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks, I've been looking for something like this for a long, long time <3 For any1 playing on 1080p the placement in the top left corner is X = -659 and Y = 380